# ctypes implementation of struct assignment in c

Tags: python, c, pointers, struct, ctypes

I've inherited some C code I am using to translate to Python code using ctypes. I've come across a line of C that I'm having trouble with:

```
int __stdcall Callback(const CoreSystem* pCoreSys) {
    UserDataStruct* pUserData = (UserDataStruct*) pCoreSys->UserData;
    ++pAppUserData->MessageCount;
    return 0;
}
```

This is an assignment in a callback function. I am reading this as:

"Set a local variable `pUserData` which is a pointer to a struct of type `UserDataStruct` (or is this a local variable which is of *type* pointer to struct?) to `pCoreSys->UserData` casted as a pointer to `UserDataStruct`". Note that `pCoreSys->UserData` is an `int`. Also note that I most likely have the interpretation of pointers a incorrect and welcome an astute reader to kindly correct me.

The second line then increments the `MessageCount` property (?) of the `struct`.

This is the `UserDataStruct`:

```
typedef struct
{
  int UserParms;
  int ErrorCode;
  __int64 MessageCount;
  unsigned char IsOSI;
  unsigned char IsCoreRunning;
  char RunStatus;
  int NumInChain;
} UserDataStruct;
```

This is `CoreSystem`:

```
struct CoreSystem {
  int UserData;
  int DLLVersion;
  int ClockUpdateInterval;
  int Status;
  int StatusData;
  const char* StatusDisplay;
  const char* TapeDisplay;
  void* Module;
  void* ThreadInstance;
};
```

This callback function is run potentially millions of times so I am assuming the pointer allows the ability to essentially keep state.

My implementation of the `struct(ure)` in Python:

```
class UserDataStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('UserParams', c_int),
        ('ErrorCode', c_int),
        ('MessageCount', c_longlong),
        ('IsOSI', c_ubyte),
        ('IsCoreRunning', c_ubyte),
        ('RunStatus', c_char),
        ('NumInChain', c_int)]
```

I've tried the following to implement the assignment line:

```
user_data = cast(pCoreSys.contents.UserData, POINTER(UserDataStruct))
```

This runs and `user_data._type_` contains the elements from the `UserDataStruct._fields_` list but I cannot seem to access them or increment them. I realize I may have to initialize the struct but then at each call of the callback function, it will be reinitialized losing the set values (?). Also, the C implementation does not seem to initialize the struct either.

Questions:

1. Have I interpreted the assignment line of C correctly?
2. How do I replicate in Python using ctypes?
3. How would I manipulate the values (increment, decrement, etc.) in the Python ctypes implementation?
4. Why (and how) is the C dev setting a variable of type struct to an integer?

Comment: After casting, access the fields directly as attributes of the dereferenced pointer, e.g. `user_data[0].MessageCount` or `user_data.contents.MessageCount`. I don't know where you got the idea to use `_type_`.

Comment: Added `CoreSystem` struct above. The `MessageCount` is actually a `__int64`, updated in edit. I was looking at `_type_` in the debugger. It (naturally) contains the field types - not any values. Thanks for your help...

Comment: It's really storing a pointer in the `int` field `UserData`. That's just wrong. This will only work in a 32-bit process. 64-bit is out of the question.

Comment: Did you solve your problem yet ?